# Iterate conditional count across list items R

Tags: r

I am attempting to count all the instances across a list of data frames where a certain variable is over a given value. I have tried to do it as so:

```
for (name in myList){
   nrow(subset(myList[[name]], var >=6))
}
```

as I found here: http://www.statisticsblog.com/2010/03/r-tip-iterating-over-list/

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in myList[[name]] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

I know that nrow works because I have used it on a specific list item outside of the loop and it succeeded. I can't seem to figure out why the error is arising. The list names are set up as so:

```
myList$`i.j.k`
```

with i, j, and k each taking on a different numerical value. I generated the list as so from a data frame read in from a .csv file:

```
myList <- split(data, f=list(data$i, data$j, data$k))
```

What is causing the error? Or, is there a better way to do a conditional count across all list elements (there are 2000+ of them, so any non-loop way would be ideal). Thanks!

Comment: Are you calling list from list? `name in myList` -> `myList[[name]]`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out thanks to the comment from @PoGibas:

Rather than

```
for (name in myList){
   nrow(subset(myList[[name]], var >=6))
}
```

it should be:

```
for (name in myList){
   nrow(subset(name, var >=6))
}
```